# Shape of tank for which water level falls at constant velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

Greeting,
I am working on a problem that involves optimizing the shape of a tank so that the level drops at a constant rate.

### Problem and my attempt

Working on the problem, here is what I know. There is an axially symmetrical tank whose wall shape is given by $f(z) = R(\frac{z}{H})^n$ which is shown in the figure. The spigot of the tank has cross-sectional area, a and there is no vena contracta. What I need to do is find $n$ so I can satisfy these conditions.

Here is what I have done so far to start on the problem. I am assuming that the area where the spigot is in the tank will not have any significant effects on the total volume of the tank if I integrate.

Doing a mass balance on the tank I get that

1. $In-out+Generation = Accumulation$ where $Generation; In = 0$
2. $-\rho Q_{out}=\frac{\rho dV}{dT}$ as a consequence of the mass balance. And since density is constant $-Q_{out}=\frac{dV}{dT}$
3. To get $Q_{out}$ use the fact that $u_2a = Q_{out}$
4. Using Bernoulli's Equation to get an expression for $u_2$. Between 1 and 2 I get $\frac{u_1^2}2+gz_1+\frac{P_1}{\rho}=\frac{u_2^2}2+gz_2+\frac{P_2}{\rho}$
5. Using the relation that $P_1=P_2=P_{atm}$ (4) can be simplified to $\frac{u_1^2}2+gz_1+=\frac{u_2^2}2+gz_2$ and saying that $u_1 = \frac{dz}{dt}$ I now have $\frac{\frac{dz}{dt}^2}2+gz_1+=\frac{u_2^2}2+gz_2$
6. Solving (5) for $u_2$ I get that $u_2 = \frac{dz}{dt} + \sqrt{2g(z_1-z_2)}$

### My issue

This is where I start to run into issues relating what I know. I know that $\frac{dz}{dt} = constant$ and I know that I need to solve for $n$ in the $f(z)$ function. I am guess that do solve equation (2) for the volume of the tank which is $a_t\frac{dz}{dt}$. I assume since $\frac{dz}{dt}$ is present on both sides it will cancel out. Why does the rate of the flow even matter though? Why is it not valid just to say that the velocity of the water in the tank will be irrelevant in comparison to the velocity coming out of the spigot? Typically that is a valid assumption, or am I in correct in that?

And one small struggle is getting the area of the tank by just knowing $f(z)$. It has been a while since I've done calculus. The first thought in my mind is a solid of revolution. I think that $f(z)$ is a function that relates z and radius so $r = f(z) = R(\frac{z}{H})^n$ and if so, would I be doing $V = \int_a^b \pi r^2 dz$ which is $ V = \int_a^b \pi R(\frac{z}{H})^n dz$? This integral seems very difficult to calculate though and leads me to believe that I have done something wrong. Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: 1. Assuming the liquid is incompressible, you can ignore mass and use volume instead. 2. What is f(z)? Is that the same as r? 3. The integral of $z^n$ is hard?? It is basic. 4. The velocity of the water in the tank is only negligible if the area of the water surface is much larger than the area of the spigot. This is not true when z is small.

Comment: I believe f(z) = r. With that, I think I realized I was way overthinking some aspects such as the integral. Would I need to integrate to get volume or could I just get the area and say that Volume is Area* $\frac{dz}{dt}$? If so I could just  do the integral of $R \frac{1}{H^n} \int_0^H z^n dz$.

Comment: @sammygerbil - you make a good point for small $z$ however i would argue that most of the mechanical energy change has already happened so this incurs only a small error. However, it is a bit weird that at $r(0)=0$ i.e. there is no outflow because the geometry is closed. OP would benefit from assuming a different form of $f\left(r\right)=\frac{r-r_0}{r_f-r_0}=\left( \frac{z-z_0}{z_f-z_0}\right )^n$ where $r_0$ corresponds to the radius of the outflow area, $a$.

Comment: @nluigi : OP can keep the form $r(z)=R(z/H)^n$ if he *does not* assume that the spigot is at $z=0$.

Comment: Your Step #6 does not follow from Step #5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for an interesting question, I never considered there is a geometry which would result in a constant decrease in height of the water surface. A couple of points you should consider:

1. Typically for these types of problem we choose a geometry where the area of the water surface $A$ is much larger than the outflow area $a$, i.e. $a/A\ll1$. From a mass balance $u_wA = u_{out}a$, it follows that $u_w/u_{out}=a/A\ll1$ or that the speed at the water surface is much smaller than at the outflow. Now since the Bernoulli equation considers the squares of the velocities this becomes even more pronounced and we can simply assume the water surface is practically stationary in terms of mechanical energy. If you then choose the coordinate system properly, i.e. the outflow is at $z=0$ the Bernoulli equation simplifies to:
   $$\frac{1}{2}v\left(t\right)^2=gh\left(t\right)$$
   where $v$ is the outflow velocity and $h$ is the height of the water surface.
2. The variable area $A\left(t\right)$ of the water surface with height needs to factor in the mass balance:
   $$\frac{dV}{dt}=-av\rightarrow\frac{d}{dt}\left(Ah\right)=-a\sqrt{2gh}$$
   Using the product rule:
   $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(Ah\right)=A\frac{dh}{dt}+h\frac{dA}{dt}$$
   The surface area is related to the radius $r\left(h\right)$ of the tank at a certain height:
   $$A=\pi r^{2}=\pi R^{2}\left(\frac{h}{H}\right)^{2n}$$
   where use was made of your function $r=f\left(h\right)$. Substituting this into the above equation yields:
   $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(Ah\right)=\left(1+2n\right)\pi R^{2}\left(\frac{h}{H}\right)^{2n}\frac{dh}{dt}$$
   and the mass balance is reduced to:
   $$\left(1+2n\right)\pi R^{2}\left(\frac{h}{H}\right)^{2n}\frac{dh}{dt}=-a\sqrt{2gh}$$
   This gives you a differential equation for $h\left(t\right)$ which is solved with the initial condition $h\left(0\right)=H$ using simple integration. It may look complex but it isn't after some rearranging. *Pro-tip: I tend to non-dimensionlize these equations to make them easier to handle. To do so rewrite the equation in terms of:
   $$\theta=\frac{h}{H}\quad\tau=\frac{t}{T}\quad T=\frac{\left(1+2n\right)\pi R^{2}H}{a\sqrt{2gH}}$$
   As a bonus this gives you the time-scale $T$ which is an order-of-magnitude estimate of how long it takes to empty the tank*
3. While the above integration isn't so difficult, to find the value of $n$ doesn't actually require solving for the profile $h\left(t\right)$. Instead, as you correctly asserted, for the rate to be constant we require:
   $$\frac{dh}{dt}=K$$ 
   where $K$ is some constant. Unfortunately, we don't know this constant so this relation can't help us in determining $n$. However, if the rate is constant what does that say about the rate of the rate, i.e. $\frac{d^2h}{dt^2}$? Use that to find $n$, which then allows you to find $K$ (which should be independent of $h$; if not then something went wrong) and finally the profile of $h$ from the differential equation (in case you are interested, you should find the profile for $h$ is linear).

Comment: Thank you for the response! I appreciate the input to the problem. I am having one small issue and that is doing the derivative of  $z \frac{d}{dt} (\pi R^2(\frac{z}{h})^{2n}) $ which should be 0 correct? which would reduce the equation to $$\pi R^{2}\left(\frac{h}{H}\right)^{2n}\frac{dh}{dt}=-a\sqrt{2gh}$$

Comment: @JuliusDariusBelosarius it is not zero because $z$ depends on $t$. If it was zero then that's the same as saying the surface area is constant.

Comment: I feel I have gotten to an answer. I got that $n=\frac{1}{4}$ which seems like a correct answer. I solved the reduced mass balance to $\frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{-a\sqrt{2gz}}{\pi R^2(\frac{z}{H})^{2n}(1+2n)}$ and then took the second derivative of it and solved for when it is 0. Assume the equation can only be zero when $1-4n=0; n=\frac{1}{4}$. I think this is proper. I am now going to find K and then solve my differential for $z(t)$ and hopefully it'll be linear. I appreciate the assistance!

Comment: @JuliusDariusBelosarius that is the answer I found as well :)

Comment: I think your assumption that the height of the water surface is constant ($\dot z=0$) contradicts the requirement that the water level decreases at a constant (ie non-zero) rate. A false assumption is likely to lead to a false conclusion.

Comment: @sammygerbil - The assumption is that $\dot{z}\lt v$ such that $\dot{z}^2\ll v^2$ so setting $\dot{z}\approx 0$ in the Bernoulli equation is not a bad assumption. It simply means that advection of the water surface contributes little to the mechanical energy balance. As with any assumption though i advise to check this once the profile for $z$ is determined.

Comment: In Step #2 you seem to be saying that the volume of liquid in the tank is $V=Ah$ where $A$ is the area of the upper surface and $h$ is the depth of liquid. But then $V=Ah$ is volume of a cylinder. This does not make sense to me.

Comment: @sammygerbil only if $A$ is constant does it become a cylinder, i.e. for $n=0$. However, $A$ is variable according to his function $f$ which makes its radius variable with height. For $n=1$ it would be a conical shape.

Comment: To the suggestor of the edit: the minus sign is correct, because the volume is decreasing with time.

Answer (score 0):

I shall assume that the spigot is connected at height $z_0$ where the radius is $r_0$, and that the liquid is at atmospheric pressure at this point. Then from Bernoulli's Equation the speed of descent $\dot z$ of the upper surface of the liquid is given by
$\dot z^2+2gz=\dot z_0^2+2gz_0$.

Assuming the fluid is incompressible then from the continuity condition we have
$\pi r^2 \dot z = \pi r_0^2 \dot z_0$
$\dot z_0 = \dot z (\frac{r}{r_0})^2 = \dot z (\frac{z}{z_0})^{2n}$.
Substitute in Bernoulli's Equation :
$\dot z^2 + 2gz = 2gz_0 + \dot z^2 (\frac{z}{z_0})^{4n}$.

$\dot z$ is constant. If this equation is to hold for all values of $z$ then comparing powers and coefficients of $z^1=z$ and $z^0=1$ on both sides we must have
$n=\frac14$
$\dot z^2 = 2gz_0$.

Comment: I like this answer because it leads to an evaluation of $n$

Comment: with fewer steps. However, your formula for $v$ is dimensionally inconsistent.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. $v$ was not in dimensionless units, whereas the other variables were. I have revised my answer.